# Error while installing Office 365

Tags: windows-7, powershell, office365

I have Windows 7 64-bit laptop. I am trying to install Office 365 on it which I get from my job. When I run it as Administrator I get this error message:

> Windows cannot find 'powershell.exe'. Make sure you typed the name
>   correctly, and then try again.

Has this happened to you guys before? What is the solution?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have Windows 7 SP1 installed?

Comment: yes. Funny thing is when I click OK button on error message and close the program, then the program restarted automatically and this time it start downloading Office 365 files. Weird. Then the installation finish and everything looks ok. You never know with Microsoft how their software would behave

Comment: It's *possible* that the installer found the error, had a check online for a solution, found one, and applied it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen when the environment variables are missing an entry for Powershell. `$env:path` must include `C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;`. As mentioned in the comments, the installer likely added this entry to your path after not finding it on the first run of the installer.

To anyone else reading this in the future, try running the installer a second time. If you encounter the error again, check your environment variables and manually add the entry for Powershell.